# Изменить регистр слов из списка в тексте

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит текст, затем он вводит слова, далее нужно вернуть текст в котором при наличии введённые слова будут в верхнем регистре.

```
txt = input("Введите текст: ")
wrl = input("Введите нужные слова: ")
txtl = txt.lower()
wrlspi = wrl.split()
txtspi = txtl.split()
for i in (txtspi):
    if i == wrlspi:
        i.upper()
j = " ".join(txtspi)
print(j)
```

Comment: Смените тему на более лаконичную, а описание внесите в тело вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = input("Введите текст: ").lower().split()
words = input("Введите нужные слова: ").lower().split()
for i, w in enumerate(phrase):
    if w in words:
        phrase[i] = w.upper()
print(" ".join(phrase))
```

```
Введите текст: от топота копыт пыль по полю летит
Введите нужные слова: пыль летит
от топота копыт ПЫЛЬ по полю ЛЕТИТ
```

Вариант покороче (списковое включение) с сохранением исходного регистра несовпавших слов

```
phrase = input("Введите текст: ").split()
words = input("Введите нужные слова: ").lower().split()
print(" ".join([w.upper() if w.lower() in words else w for w in phrase]))
```

```
Введите текст: От топота копыт пыль По полю ЛеТиТ
Введите нужные слова: ПыЛь ЛетиТ
От топота копыт ПЫЛЬ По полю ЛЕТИТ
```